# Opening a closed case by editing a form submission

Tags: commcare

Within a workflow for a program, there is a chance that a beneficiary is interviewed and can trigger a case close, but later receive treatment that would require additional forms to be filled out.

Is there a way to allow edits to the form that closed the case (IE change the answers to the questions that caused the form to close), or is the only way to open the case back up to archive the form and fill it out once more?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, CommCareHQ will block you from editing a form which modifies a closed case. I believe you'll have to do as you were saying and archive the form that closes that case and resubmit it.

There may also be a way to open the case back up using the case importer, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah, found the answer:
"Note: It is not currently possible to reopen a closed case using the Excel Importer. To do that you must use the Archive Forms tool to archive the form which closed the case. Closing a case using Excel Importer creates a submission for an "unknown" form in the case history, which can be archived to undo closing, i.e., reopening, the case."
https://wiki.commcarehq.org/display/commcarepublic/Closing+Cases

Can't open cases with the importer.